# Conditional rendering not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component that I want to render a placeholder skeleton when the page first loads. Is loading is set to true on the first render and then after an API call it will be flipped to false but for some reason the skeleton never loads. It always chooses to ignore the first part and then just load the cards

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ImageBackground } from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import  { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation'
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import ShimmerPlaceHolder from 'react-native-shimmer-placeholder'

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width

const VerticalCard = ({name, image, navigation, stars, isLoading}) => {

    const renderCards = () => {
        if (isLoading) {
            return <ShimmerPlaceHolder style={{ height: 100 }}/>
            
        } else {
            return(
                <View>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.8} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('category', {name})} >
                <Image style={styles.image}  source={{uri: image}} />
                <Text style={styles.text} >{name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.stars}>{`${stars} stars`}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                
            </View>
            )
        }
    }
    
    return (
      renderCards()
    )
}

export default withNavigation(VerticalCard)
```

Comment: You might be getting an error while compiling. Am I right ?

Comment: No error it still works is the weird thing. Just not ever showing the skeleton. When I take off the line that turns isloading back to false then thee skeletons show up and they work but obviously, they should be on from the start and then get flipped off

Comment: Can you please add code of how you rendered or where you called this component ?